# Bad Request Check `Errors` for a list of errors returned by the API. at SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I'm using send grid to send an email after a user is created and I'm following This tutorial Here
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity
I even downloaded This tutorial and wrote code as it is

but it code breaks at  this

```
string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(uApp.Id);
string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, uApp.Id, Request);
 manager.SendEmail(uApp.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

Its This third like

```
manager.SendEmail(uApp.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

Where code breaks

and the errors is like this

> Exceptions.InvalidApiRequestException: Bad Request Check `Errors` for
>   a list of errors returned by the API. at SendGrid.Web.d__c.MoveNext() 
>   -- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task 
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at
>   SendGrid.Web.d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at
>   GCRweb.EmailService.d__0.MoveNext()

and bla bla bla 
**before this it was giving me an error on first line abot some token and stuff** 
What is that I'm doing wrong

Comment: You can see the `Error`-list while debugging..

Comment: I did that and not very much helpful

Comment: Could you prove more code? I think you are missing the code in `SendMail()`

Comment: sendMail is a built in  function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd tried that one but I think the best you can do is create your own function for this  Here is a proper solution

```
public static bool ForgotPassword(string fromAccount, string toAccount, string subject, string msg)
    {
        var ConfirmationMail = new MailMessage();
        if (IsLiveMode)
        {
            ConfirmationMail = new MailMessage("abc@abc.com", toAccount, subject, msg);
        }
        else
        {
            ConfirmationMail = new MailMessage("abc@abc.com", toAccount, subject, msg);
                       }
         ConfirmationMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        ConfirmationMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            objSMTPClient.Send(ConfirmationMail);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the config file

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>    
  <smtp from="no-reply@no-reply.com">
    <network host="smtp.live.com" password="abcdefghijk" port="587" userName="atteeqKhawaja@msn.com" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>     
</mailSettings>
```

and final code is like this now

```
string code = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code, Request);

            bool emailSent = ForgotPassword(" khawaja Atteeq", Email.Text, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

Answer (score 7):

InvalidApiRequestException exception is the key.

The best way to handle errors using DeliverAsync() method is something like this:

```
            try
            {
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(mensaje);
            }
            catch (InvalidApiRequestException ex)
            {
                var detalle = new StringBuilder();

                detalle.Append("ResponseStatusCode: " + ex.ResponseStatusCode + ".   ");
                for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count(); i++)
                {
                    detalle.Append(" -- Error #" + i.ToString() + " : " + ex.Errors[i]);
                }

                throw new ApplicationException(detalle.ToString(), ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, check the Web.config. The original tutorial had said to use value="[Sendgridname]", after removing the [ ] it should work fine. See below.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="emailServiceUserName" value="SendGridUserName" />
    <add key="emailServicePassword" value="SendGridPassword" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: exactly what happened to me